# Tire with lower rolling resistance

Tags: mountain-bike, tire

I would like to replace the knobby tires for my MTB with some that will have less rolling resistance.

Is this a good choice?
[https://www.amazon.com/Schwinn-Replacement-Kevlar-hybrid-comfort/dp/B0088X3VL6/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0088X3VL6)

They will be replacing these tires.

[image]

Comment: Words like "hybrid" and "comfort", or "puncture-resistant"  are incompatible with "fast" or "low rolling resistance"

Comment: @Criggie unfortunately in many cases "fast" is also incompatible with low rolling resistance.  There's not that many fast tyres out there, but every brand claims many of their tyres are fast :(

Comment: If you can find someone with the same tires, listen to them running on a straight smooth road. The more noise the make, the more energy they are wasting.

Comment: “Is this a good choice?” IMO, no. That’s what I would call a “garbage tire”

Comment: @RayButterworth actually thin race tires and deep carbon rims are quite loud because there isn't anything to absorb the vibrations.

Answer (score 8):

Nobody knows for sure, but there is a good chance that the tire in question is not great. For actual measured rolling resistance numbers, one good reference is [bicyclerollingresistance.com](https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/). For tires that are similar to the one you're asking about, check under "touring tires". The site tests mostly 28" tires, but many of the touring tire models are available in 26" size as well.

Comment: I ordered some touring tires. S**lite Kross Plus Cyclocross/Hybrid @ojs

Comment: @fixit7 thanks for letting me know, don’t blame me when it turns out they’re not very good

Comment: I will not blame you. :-) @ojs

Comment: Those new touring tires do offer noticeably less rolling resistance. For a given effort, I achieved a higher speed.

Answer (score -3):

Generally resistance is measured by the amount of friction between the rubber and deformation so your looking at the skinniest threat tire with lowest weight, you could make your current tire with less resistance by just sanding it and making the rubber threat similar to a road bike one

Comment: The suppleness of the tyre casing and sidewall is just as important as that of the actual tread. If you’ve ever handled a high-performance tyre it’s amazing how flexible and supple they are. Almost like a piece of fabric. Some tyres with relatively low rolling resistance have surprisingly thick tread (e.g. Schwalbe Marathon has 7.3mm tread/center thickness).